# Unable to install a package in ubuntu-core-14.04-core-armhf

Tags: 14.04, arm, ubuntu-core

I am using Ubuntu based rootfs on arm devices for the first time, and need some help

I am using the `ubuntu-core-14.04-core-armhf.tar.gz`

I want to install a package called as evtest which can be seen in [this link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/armhf?text=evtest).

How do I add this source in my

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

My sources.list has all the default entries.

I did a lot of search and could not find a solution for the same. Could some one please point me out the same.

Answer (score 0):

Snaps are downloaded from the Ubuntu One Store, hence you can run

```
snap find
```

or

```
snap find package-name
```

then

```
sudo snap install package-name
```

I doubt but check if this works for you

```
sudo snap install evtest_1.31-1_armhf.deb
```